# Python: Use regex to create a list of lists based on text sentences separated by ".", "?", or "!"

Tags: python, regex, list, text

I have the following sample text that I already cleaned.  Below is just a sample of it:

```
and can you by no drift of circumstance get from him why he puts on this confusion grating so harshly all his days of 
quiet with turbulent and dangerous lunacy? he does confess he feels himself distracted. but from what cause he will by 
no means speak. nor do we find him forward to be sounded but with a crafty madness keeps aloof when we would bring 
him on to some confession of his true state. did he receive you well? most like a gentleman. but with much forcing of 
his disposition. niggard of question. but of our demands most free in his reply.
```

I want to do the following:

- create a list of lists named hamsplits, such that hamsplits[i] is a list of all the words in the i-th sentence of the text.
- sentences should be stored in the order that they appear, and so should the words within each sentence
- sentences end with '.', '?', and '!'

Desired output example:

```
hamsplits[0] == ['and', 'can', 'you', 'by', ..., 'dangerous', 'lunacy']
```

I tried the code below using just '.' as a test but it doesn't return list of lists:

```
hamsplits3 = hamsplits2.split('.')
```

Instead it returns this:

```
['\n\nand can you by no drift of circumstance get from him why he puts on this confusion grating so harshly all his days of \nquiet with turbulent and dangerous lunacy? he does confess he feels himself distracted', ' but from what cause he will by \nno means speak', ' nor do we find him forward to be sounded but with a crafty madness keeps aloof when we would bring \nhim on to some confession of his true state', ' did he receive you well? most like a gentleman', ' but with much forcing of \nhis disposition', ' niggard of question', ' but of our demands most free in his reply', " did you assay him? ... ]
```

What am I doing wrong?  I don't want to use any imported packages outside of `import re`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `findall`

```py
import re

s = """and can you by no drift of circumstance get from him why he puts on this confusion grating so harshly all his days of 
quiet with turbulent and dangerous lunacy? he does confess he feels himself distracted. but from what cause he will by 
no means speak. nor do we find him forward to be sounded but with a crafty madness keeps aloof when we would bring 
him on to some confession of his true state. did he receive you well? most like a gentleman. but with much forcing of 
his disposition. niggard of question. but of our demands most free in his reply."""

hamsplits = [i.strip().replace('\n', '').split(' ') for i in re.findall(r'[^.?!]+', s, re.MULTILINE)]

print(hamplist[0])
```

**Output:**

```
['and', 'can', 'you', 'by', 'no', 'drift', 'of', 'circumstance', 'get', 'from', 'him', 'why', 'he', 'puts', 'on', 'this', 'confusion', 'grating', 'so', 'harshly', 'all', 'his', 'days', 'of', 'quiet', 'with', 'turbulent', 'and', 'dangerous', 'lunacy']
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this.

```
import re
with open('input_text.txt') as file:
  hamsplits =[ele.split() for ele in re.split('[.?!]',file.read())]
print(hamsplits[0])
```

output:

```
['and', 'can', 'you', 'by', 'no', 'drift', 'of', 'circumstance', 'get', 'from', 'him', 'why', 'he', 'puts', 'on', 'this', 'confusion', 'grating', 'so', 'harshly', 'all', 'his', 'days', 'of', 'quiet', 'with', 'turbulent', 'and', 'dangerous', 'lunacy']
```